# Set ylabel coordinates in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How on earth do I set the coordinates for the ylabel? I am using logscale on the y-axis. I though it was the simple:

`set ylabel "labelname" xcord,ycord`

so for example when I enter

`set ylabel "F-norm" 0,2`

It says "unexpected or unrecognized token" and points to the 0. I know this should be a very simple thing but I haven't found a clear answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In general you don't need to set any coordinate for the ylabel

```
set ylabel "ylabel"
```

However, if this automatic position doesn't fit your expectation you may specify an `offset`

```
set ylabel "ylabel" offset 0,2
```